# Adding multiple timers to one html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to add two countdown timers to a template i got online.I am having problems figuring out how to add a second date .

HTML:

```
<div class="fullwidth colour1 clearfix">
<div id="countdown" class="bodycontainer clearfix" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-fade', delay: 300, repeat: true}">
    <h1>Date1</h1>
    <div id="countdowncont" class="clearfix">
        <ul id="countscript">
            <li>
                <span class="days">00</span>
                <p>Days</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="hours">00</span>
                <p>Hours</p>
            </li>
            <li class="clearbox">
                <span class="minutes">00</span>
                <p>Minutes</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="seconds">00</span>
                <p>Seconds</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "";
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "01 May 2017 12:00:00",       /** Enter new date here **/
        format: "on"
    },
    function() {
        // callback function
    });
});
```

This is the countdown plug in that was requested from the below comments :

```
  (function($) {
$.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
    //custom 'this' selector
    thisEl = $(this);
    //array of custom settings
    var settings = { 
        'date': null,
        'format': null
    };
    //append the settings array to options
    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }
    //main countdown function
    function countdown_proc() {
        eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
        currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
        if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
            callback.call(this);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
        days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days 
        seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed
        hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed
        //conditional Ss
        if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
        if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
        if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
        if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }
        //logic for the two_digits ON setting
        if(settings['format'] == "on") {
            days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "00" + days;
            hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "00" + hours;
            minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "00" + minutes;
            seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
        }
        //update the countdown's html values.
        if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
            thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
            thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
            thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
            thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
        } else { 
            alert("19 April 2016 11:12:00");
            clearInterval(interval); 
        }
    }
    //run the function
    countdown_proc();
    //loop the function
    interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);
}
```

}) (jQuery);

I would appreciate any help.Thanks

Comment: by second date you mean a second countdown? can you link to the jquery countdown plugin you're using?

Comment: From your code it looks like you are trying to add a second date to the same timer.  I doubt the timer will function that way (though I don't know for sure because I don't know which timer plugin you are using).  My best guess is you need to duplicate the html using a distinct id (maybe id="countdown2") and then initialize that one like you did the first one.

Comment: Change the ID of the second timer HTML, then duplicate the jQuery using the new ID. Am I missing something?

Comment: hi , i have added the code in above .

Comment: I have added the code in above .I have tried to duplicate these codes but change the class names and file names but the both timers still try and call from the original countdown.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
//add first date 
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#countdown::nth-child(1)").countdown({
        date: "01 May 2017 12:00:00",       /** Enter new date here **/
        format: "on"
    },
    function() {
        // callback function
    });

    //add second date
    $("#countdown::nth-child(2)").countdown({
        date: "01 May 2017 12:00:00",       /** Enter new date here **/
        format: "on"
    },
    function() {
        // callback function
    });

});
```

and I suggest you use countdown as class name rather than id